# how to build wsp in visual studio 2012 without actually deploying the project

Tags: solution-package, solution-deployment

I am trying to create a wsp for my project in visual studio 2012. when i build my project it is not creating a wsp only when i deploy my project it is creating a wsp in my bin/debug folder.

Is there any way i can create a wsp without deploying my project everytime to my sharepoint site.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can build and publish WSP without deploying solution.There is 'Publish' option in visual studio 2012, click on it & specify hard drive folder path to publish WSP.

First bulid your solution then **Right click** on project in solution explorer-->**Publish**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MSBuild** to build the packages (particularly helpful if you want to automate the build process as part of TFS)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231588.aspx

or use a plugin like **CKSDev for Visual Studio** (which i personally use) to give you an option to build packages from the IDE itself.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cf1225b4-aa83-4282-b4c6-34feec8fc5ec